# Corner ribbon in responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to align the corner ribbon to my image. here's what I managed to do:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <a href="http://website.com">
                    <img src="/images/web1.jpg"><div class="ribbon"><span>Featured</span></div></img>
                </a><br><br>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <a href="http://website.com">
                    <img src="/images/web2.jpg"><div class="ribbon"><span>Featured</span></div></img>
                </a><br><br>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the css

```
.ribbon {
   position: absolute;
   right: 62px; top: -5px;
   z-index: 1;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 75px; 
   height: 75px; 
   text-align: right;
}
.ribbon span {
   font-size: 10px;
   color: #fff; 
   text-transform: uppercase; 
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   width: 100px; display: block;
   background: #79A70A;
   background: linear-gradient(#9BC90D 0%, #79A70A 100%);
   box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
   position: absolute;
   top: 19px; right: -21px;
}

.ribbon span::before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute; 
   left: 0px; top: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
   border-left: 3px solid #79A70A;
   border-right: 3px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
   border-top: 3px solid #79A70A;
}
.ribbon span::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute; 
   right: 0%; top: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
   border-right: 3px solid #79A70A;
   border-left: 3px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
   border-top: 3px solid #79A70A;
}
```

the ribbon works fine if I put a fixed height and width, but how do I make the ribbon stick to the right corner of the image? Thanks

EDITED

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="wrappersa"> <a href="http://website.com">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/web3.jpg" />
                    <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green">
                        <div class="ribbon-green">New</div>
                    </div>
                    </a><br><br>
                    <p><strong>Website</strong<br>This is a website</p><br><hr>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .wrappersa {
        margin: 20px auto;
        width: 450px;
        height: 430px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .ribbon-wrapper-green {
        width: 85px;
        height: 88px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: -3px;
        right: -3px;
    }
    .ribbon-green {
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 20px;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        width: 100px;
        display: block;
        background: #79A70A;
        background: linear-gradient(#9BC90D 0%, #79A70A 100%);
        box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        position: absolute;
        top: 19px;
        right: -21px;
    }
    .ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        border-left: 3px solid #79A70A;
        border-right: 3px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top: 3px solid #79A70A;
    }

@media (max-width : 992px) {
    .wrappersa {
        margin: 20px auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is invalid HTML – an `img` element can not have children. And perhaps you should just position the outer `a` element relative, so that you have an anchor point for the absolute position of it’s descendants.

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help but as you said, the ribbon doesn't truly take into account if the image size is dynamically changed so all image sizes have to be fixed and the same.

Updated with bottom text caption.

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
}
figure img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
figure figcaption {
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #9BC90D;
}
.wrapper a {
  color: #fff;
}
/*****************/

.wrapper {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 430px;
  position: relative;
}
.ribbon-wrapper-green {
  width: 85px;
  height: 88px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
}
.ribbon-green {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: #79A70A;
  background: linear-gradient(#9BC90D 0%, #79A70A 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: -21px;
}
.ribbon-green:before,
.ribbon-green:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid #79A70A;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #79A70A;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .wrapper {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="https://something.io">
          <figure>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/950x500/1c1c1c/fff/?text=Image" />
            <figcaption><strong>Website</strong>
              <br>This is a website
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
          <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green">
            <div class="ribbon-green">New</div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="https://something.io">
          <figure>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/950x500/1c1c1c/fff/?text=Image" />
            <figcaption><strong>Website</strong>
              <br>This is a website
            </figcaption>
          </figure>

          <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green">
            <div class="ribbon-green">New</div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to make the ribbon responsive as well?

Comment: Ok, how do I get the ribbon to be responsive and aligned to the image? because my current image is 950x500. if I have to fix a width for it, i'd have to fix quite a few. thanks

Comment: All your images are 950x500 or they all have different sizes?

Comment: They are all the same size. the max-width for the images are 950x500 and they're responsive. so it'll be auto scaling down to fit the screen size.

Comment: Since they're all the same dimensions you can adjust the CSS rules to accommodate those sizes as well as the media queries. Check out the updated code snippet in full screen mode.

Comment: The code works a lot better, but i'm still having some problems with it. once I add a description under the image, it cuts off the words. I added the height of the wrapper and that helped. When viewing from a 7 inch tab, with two columns a row, the image aligns to the left with the ribbon on it's own on the right. any ideas why? I updated the code. thanks

Comment: The HTML you just added is not complete.

Comment: Sorry, missed the last div. basically the only thing left is how do I align it to the image? because if i'm not mistaken, when viewing on a tab, the ribbon aligns itself to the column div instead of the image. due to the @media?